# Как монтировать флешку в терминале в виртуальной машине?

Tags: linux, консоль, linux-mint, grub, root

Требуется стянуть файлы `passwd` и `shadow` с ПК. Через grub запустил терминал от root'a, но флешку не видит. Читал много статей в которых все начиналось с команды `fdisk`, но у меня там только сам диск с ОС. Как же тогда получить доступ к флешке из терминала? Возможно есть другие способы забрать файлы?

*P.S. ОС Linux Mint 19.2 (виртуальная машина).*

Answer (score 1):

К виртуальной машине флешку нужно подключить. Обычно это делается кнопкой. Устройство будет видно в `dmesg`. После подключения драйвер не загрузится автоматически потому что udev не запущен.

Напишите чтоб загрузить драйвера для флешки

```
modprobe usb-storage
modprobe scsi_mod
modprobe sd_mod
```

Если всё успешно, то смотрите в `ls /dev/sd*`. Там появится новая буква
потом

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/
```